# Why this if logic isnot short circuiting?

Tags: unity, c#, scripting

I've this script in **UNITY** to check if the `hit` RayCastHid2D variable has some gameobject with `hole` tag or a parent gameobject with `hole` tag when I Raycast...

```
if (hit.collider != null && (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "hole" || (hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject != null && hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.tag == "hole")))
```

Everything is fine until `if (hit.collider != null && (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "hole" ||`

but when I enter `(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject != null && hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.tag == "hole")` it throws a `NullReferenceException`....

**But why?**

It supposed to short circuit here `hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject != null &&` if there's no parent gameobject!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer :D

It'll be `hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent != null`